# When is it appropriate in the US to give a boss a gift?

Tags: management, gifts

Based on some comments in [Asked to pay for a group gift that I have previously declined to contribute](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/60194/asked-to-pay-for-a-group-gift-that-i-have-previously-declined-to-contribute), are there times when it is appropriate to give your boss a gift?  If so, what are appropriate gifts?

I've always read that gifts should only flow down, so bosses can give gifts to workers, but the gifts should not go the other way.  If there are exceptions, what are they?

Edit: there probably should be a question for other countries too, since from the answers so far, it can vary depending on country.  Therefore, I am specifically interested in the US.

Comment: This could well depend on culture that could vary from place to place.

Comment: Buying as a group with anonymous contributions is a safer bet but still don't go overboard.   Let's say a boss worked hard to get you a (good) transfer then maybe a inexpensive direct gift.  A gift to thank for a bonus or raise - no.

Comment: this very much depends where you are, in some countries getting your boss a gift is expected and can influence your prospects of advancement.

Comment: I think Secret Santa deserves a honorable mention.

Comment: If you consider the bods a personal friend, and it would be appropriate to give a personal friend that gift, and you want to give that gift, and there is no chance of it being misunderstood as bribing/flattering the boss, and it doesn't violate company policies or labor laws... then it may be appropriate. Otherwise, no. (That leaves enough room for secret santa, baby shower, and the like while stating clearly that if in doubt , don't.)

Comment: @JBKing: Yes, of course, but there are still some general guidelines. Writing a birthday card for your boss is probably ok almost everywhere, a trip to the Caribbean is probably overdoing it.

Answer (score 6):

It depends.

... on a lot of things.

- **Cultural aspects**. Employee/manager relationships vary around the world and need to be considered. Some manager-employee relationships are very hierarchal and less flat. I can't even generalize here because it will depend on how cultures view gifts, too. Parts of the world practically operate on subtle (or not subtle) bribes and this fits right in. Parts see a small gift as effectively a fairly socially unacceptable bribe.
- **Company culture**. Do people often get gifts for each other? Is this normal? Will it come across as trying to buy favor with the boss?
- **Company regulations/policies.** Many companies probably have policies against this, at least formally. The last thing you want to do in giving a gift is get your boss in trouble.
- **What is a gift?** This might seem silly but... what is a gift? Is it offering to take some of your bosses on call time? How about buying a nice giftcard? What about a thankful note? Keep in mind that all these could be considered gifts - but some people might not seem them that way.
- **Friendship with boss**. Is your boss your friend? How does your team work? Or is your boss just your manager? Friendship can make gifts not much easier or worse, depending on cultural factors above. But for me personally it'd be much easier to give a gift to someone I felt was a friend/colleague rather than "just" my manager.

Those factors are going to dramatically impact the question of, "how/when is it appropriate to give a gift to your boss?" so my recommendation for a more practical approach would be:

1. Talk to your colleagues. Ideally, a mentor figure who you can confide in - tell them you were thinking of thanking/appreciating your boss and wondering what the best way to do it is.
2. Verify with your HR department it is ok.

In most cases I think that if you have to ask - you probably shouldn't.

---

Realistically, if you want to appreciate your manager, send a nice, specific, and appreciative email to them and/or their boss..

Comment: I am not sure this is an answer.  You list topics or discussion points but offer no advice on what gift would be acceptable or not given the culture, company, and so on.  Why would HR or another employee want their time wasted on answering a gift question?

Comment: +1 for 'What is a gift?' I'm deeply appreciative even when an associate grabs me a coffee out getting their own. Courtesy in itself is a good gift, IMO.

Answer (score 2):

1. Depends heavily on culture. Not just of the country, but the company.
2. Depends on the relationship within the team.
3. Sometimes it may depend on company policy (although probably only in larger organizations)

I will speak of my own experience, as generalizing is diffcult (the question is broad).

At my old job I would sometimes bring homemade treats to share with the team, and knowing that my boss loves sweets/has kids I would specifically bring him a little Tupperware container with a few extra slices for his family. It was acceptable because he was very approachable, loved to talk about his family, genuinely appreciated what I gave him, and I also shared with the team.

At my current job I've considered getting some people around the office (my boss and others) some gag gifts such as humorous mugs that I feel *really* fit them, but I will draw the line at anything over 5 dollars or so, and only do it for people I genuinely get along with.

Would I buy my boss an expensive gift? No. A good rule of thumb might be observing how he treats you on ***your*** birthday, and simply mimicking the behavior (if it's not rude)

Would I go out of my way to celebrate his birthday? No, although I will wish him a heartfelt "Happy Birthday", and make sure that he knows I remembered.

And so, your question is very difficult to answer. Remember to:

**1.** Set boundaries (don't get too personal, don't get too expensive, or flashy)

and

**2.** Don't be seen as trying to buy his favor (aka bring something in for the whole team every once in a while, etc).

Answer (score -2):

Get your boss a gift if you want to.  It should be something that they would personally enjoy and not be expensive.  Even better if you made it or it was hard to find.  If you want to stay safe, don't spend a lot of money.