# What is the current protocol for holiday gifts?

Tags: holidays, gifts

I've been at the new job for about 3 months, and all seems to be going well. I report directly to two managers, and I'm on good/excellent terms with both of them. I want to give them some small holiday gifts, but I don't want to alienate coworkers or make anyone feel obligated to give me anything.

I could

- Give all my managers and coworkers a gift. It's a small shop, I could probably afford it, but it would put a bigger dent in my wallet than I would like. Plus, I don't work anywhere near as closely with any of my coworkers as I do my managers, so I know a lot less about what they would like.
- Give just the managers a gift, and try to keep it quiet. May or may not stay that way.
- Give just the managers a gift, and be open about it. Might look like currying favor.
- Try to organize some secret santa-type arrangement. Cumbersome and potentially futile.

Comment: There is no global protocol on "holiday gifts".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When is it appropriate in the US to give a boss a gift?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/60217/when-is-it-appropriate-in-the-us-to-give-a-boss-a-gift)

Comment: One possibility: Buy everyone a present, except the managers. Another possibility: Buy everyone a present who is not on a good salary. Another possibility: Buy everyone a _tiny_ present.

Comment: You don't have to do anything. If you wan't to give something then bring a box of candy shortly before the holidays for everyone to share.

Answer (score 3):

Most people don’t give each other Christmas gifts.

If you’re not sure of the custom in your team, ask your colleagues. But assume that it’s not the norm.

Answer (score 3):

I can only speak for my own workplace but buying anyone a gift would not have your desired effect. Buying just for the managers would be looked at as sucking up to them whether or not I was open about it, buying everyone a gift would be viewed as needless and organizing secret santa as awkward and best left to management if they are **really** enthusiastic.

If you are in an office such as mine then a nice alternative for showing your gratitude would be to buy the "office" a gift, such as a nice new coffee machine and if you are feeling particularly festive you could even put a small Christmas ornament on it.

Comment: That sounds like a nice alternative

Comment: "would be looked at as sucking up to them" - including by the managers.